# Stack - Implemented as Singly Linked List

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, stack

Note: I do know that Python libraries provide a `Linked List` and `Stack`. This implementation has been done to practice `Python` and some of the `data structures and Algorithms.`

I have implemented `Stack` as a `Singly Linked-List`, feel free to make suggestions.
Note: code works

Targeted Big O:

```
search: O(n), Push and Pop: O(1)
```

Methods:

```
push(value)- for insertion
pop()- for removing
is_empty()- to check if empty
peek()- look at what head holds without poping
stack_search(value)-find a value
length()-get size
```

Classes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.front = None 

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0

    def push(self, value):
        #make new node
        new_node = Node(value)
        self.count += 1

        if self.head is not None:
            #make new node point to the old node
            new_node.front = self.head
        # make head point to the new element
        self.head = new_node

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def pop(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            self.count -= 1
            temp = self.head.data
            # make head point to the node after the node that will be poped
            self.head = self.head.front
            return temp
        else:
            print("can not pop items from an empty list")

    def peek(self):
        return self.head.data

    def __iter__(self):
        # start from the node that head refers to
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.front

    def stack_search(self, value):
        # start from the head
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            # make p reference to next node
            if p.front is not None:
                if p.data == value:
                    print("Found value")
                    return p.data
                p = p.front
            else:
                print("fail")
                return 0

    def length(self):
        return self.count
```

Test:

```
from stack_Queue import Stack

def main():

    print("-------Test Stack----------")
    print("------Test push-------")
    my_stack = Stack()
    test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, -2000000, 'a', 500000, 50]

    for i in test_list:
        my_stack.push(i)
    print("-------Push Done------")
    print("-------Dump stack-----")
    for i in my_stack:
        print(i.data)
    print("-----Dump stack Done---")
    print("----check count-------")
    print("should be: 8")
    print(my_stack.length())
    print("-----check count Done--")
    print("-------Test pop $ print remaining stack--------")

    my_stack.pop()
    for i in my_stack:
        print(i.data)
    print("-----Test pop Done-----")
    print("-----Test search-------")
    x = my_stack.stack_search('a')
    print(x)
    print("---Test search Done---")

    print("-----Test pop - full stack & print what is being poped-----")
    while my_stack.length() > 0:
        x = my_stack.pop()
        print(x)
    print("-----Test pop Done-----")
    print("-----Test Empty Stack-----")
    for i in my_stack:
        print(i.data)
    print("---------Done---------")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
-------Test Stack----------
------Test push-------
-------Push Done------
-------Dump stack-----
50
500000
a
-2000000
4
3
2
1
-----Dump stack Done---
----check count-------
should be: 8
8
-----check count Done--
-------Test pop $ print remaining stack--------
500000
a
-2000000
4
3
2
1
-----Test pop Done-----
-----Test search-------
Found value
a
---Test search Done---
-----Test pop - full stack & print what is being poped-----
500000
a
-2000000
4
3
2
1
-----Test pop Done-----
-----Test Empty Stack-----
---------Done---------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your `stack_search` function re-implements loop over your linked-list. Instead of that you can use your `__iter__` itself to keep in DRY. Plus it should `True` or `False` instead of `1` and `0`.

  The Pythonic way will be implement `__contains__` to check if your container type contains an item. Then you could simply do `'a' in my_stack`.

  ```
  def __contains__(self, value):
      return value in (node.data for node in self)
  ```
- Instead of `length` method implement [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__). This will work with Python's built-in `len()`.

  Plus after defining this you won't need the method `is_empty` either as [`__len__` can be used to check for falsyness](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing): `if my_stack: ...`. You could also define [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) based on `self.head` for checking falsiness instead of using `__len__`, but it would be redundant in my opinion.
- `pop()` should raise an exception when the stack is empty, for example `list.pop`, `dict.pop`, `deque.pop` all raise some error for it.
- `Stack().peek()` currently raises an `AttributeError`. Instead of that you should be raising some custom exception when the stack is empty.