# Queue Implemented as Single Linked List

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, queue

Note: I do know that Python libraries provide a Linked list and Stack. This implementation has been done to practice Python and some of the data structures and algorithms.

I have implemented Queue as a Single linked list. Feel free to make suggestions. Note: The code works.

Targeted Big O:

Search: O(n), EnQueue and DeQueue: O(1)

Methods:

```
en_queue(value): insert values
de_queue(): remove values
is_empty(): check to see if Queue is empty
peek_front(): look at what head points to without removing
peek_back(): look at what tail points to without removing
search(value): check to see if a value is in the Queue
length(): return size
```

Classes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.front = None



class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0

    def en_queue(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)

        if self.tail is not None:
            # make the front attribute of old node point to new node
            self.tail.front = new_node

        else:
            # if first ever node in Queue both front and tail will point to it
            self.head = new_node

        self.tail = new_node
        self.count += 1

    def de_queue(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            # point head to next node
            self.head = self.head.front
            print("sucess")
            self.count -= 1
        else:
            print("Empty QUEUE")

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.front

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.head is None and self.tail is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def peek_front(self):
        return self.head.data

    def peek_back(self):
        return self.tail.data

    def queue_search(self, value):
        # start from the head
        p = self.head
        while p is not None:
            # make p reference to next node
            if p.front is not None:
                if p.data == value:
                    print("Found value")
                    return p.data
                p = p.front
            else:
                print("fail")
                return 0


    def length(self):
        return self.count
```

Test:

```
from stack_Queue import Queue


def main():

    print("-------Test Queue---------")
    print("-------Test En Queue------")
    my_queue = Queue()
    test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, -2000000, 'a', 500000, 50]

    for i in test_list:
        my_queue.en_queue(i)
    print("-------En Queue Done-------")
    for i in my_queue:
        print(i.data)
    print("------Queue Print Done-----")
    print("------Queue Print Done-----")
    print(my_queue.peek_back())
    print(my_queue.peek_front())
    print("----------De Queue---------")
    my_queue.de_queue()
    print("--------De Queue Done------")
    for i in my_queue:
        print(i.data)
    print("-----Queue Print Done------")
    print("-----Test search-------")
    x = my_queue.queue_search('a')
    print(x)
    print("-------Full De Queue-------")
    while my_queue.length() != 0:
        my_queue.de_queue()
    print("--------De Queue Done------")
    for i in my_queue:
        print(i.data)
    print("-----Queue Print Done------")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
-------Test Queue---------
-------Test En Queue------
-------En Queue Done-------
1
2
3
4
-2000000
a
500000
50
------Queue Print Done-----
------Queue Print Done-----
50
1
----------De Queue---------
sucess
--------De Queue Done------
2
3
4
-2000000
a
500000
50
-----Queue Print Done------
-----Test search-------
Found value
a
-------Full De Queue-------
sucess
sucess
sucess
sucess
sucess
sucess
sucess
--------De Queue Done------
-----Queue Print Done------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: My points from my [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/173913/12680) will be applicable to this as well. I am not sure about posting it here again.

Comment: yes yes indeed and i will implement them to this as well, i just did not want to create clutter, and taught since they are a bit different to post them separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the points I had mentioned in my [previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/173913/12680) to your `Stack` implementation.

Your `Queue` is not introspectable right now as it lacks `__repr__` method. Due to this you won't be able to view its items easily. Hence you could add `__repr__` to both `Node` and `Queue` class(same applicable to your `Stack` class in other [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173906/12680)).

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.front = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)


class EmptyQueueException(Exception):
    pass


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0

    def en_queue(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)

        if self.tail is not None:
            # make the front attribute of old node point to new node
            self.tail.front = new_node
        else:
            # if first ever node in Queue both front and tail will point to it
            self.head = new_node

        self.tail = new_node
        self.count += 1

    def de_queue(self):
        if self:
            # point head to next node
            self.head = self.head.front
            self.count -= 1
        else:
            raise EmptyQueueException()

    def peek_front(self):
        if self:
            return self.head.data
        raise EmptyQueueException()

    def peek_back(self):
        if self:
            return self.tail.data
        raise EmptyQueueException()

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.front

    def __bool__(self):
        return not (self.head is None and self.tail is None)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in (node.data for node in self)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Queue<{nodes}>'.format(nodes=', '.join(repr(node) for node in self))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> my_queue
Queue<1, 2, 3, 4, -2000000, 'a', 500000, 50>
>>> my_queue.de_queue()  # Probably want to return the value as well?
>>> my_queue
Queue<2, 3, 4, -2000000, 'a', 500000, 50>
>>> my_queue.peek_back()
50
>>> 'a' in my_queue
True
>>> 'spam' in my_queue
False
>>> bool(my_queue)
True
>>> len(my_queue)
7
>>> len(Queue())
0    
>>> bool(Queue())
False
>>> Queue().peek_back()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmptyQueueException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In `en_queue()`, the pythonic way to express `if self.tail is not None:` is `if self.tail:`

Comment: If the intention is to explicitly check against `None` then `is not None` is fine.